# Gzipped JSON response to file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone have a working example of taking a gzipped JSON response from and API endpoint and saving it directly to a file please?

Having issues with Heroku's memory limits when I decompress a very large API response before writing to a file. It would be good to completely bypass decompression as all I want to do is take the response as given and upload as a file to Google Cloud Storage.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I should add that the data is only available via POST so using open-uri doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows you what actually happens when you use "Accept-Encoding" and set it to gzip. If the accept header is set to gzip the body of the response is the actual compressed data and you could pipe it to `gunzip`, example follows.

I got this from here....

https://gist.github.com/joho/3747653

When you run it run it like this

```
ruby http_gzip.rb | gunzip -c
```

This will download the gzipped google search result...

```
require 'net/http'

debug = Proc.new{|msg| STDERR.puts "[#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}] #{msg}" }

page = nil 
http = Net::HTTP.new( "www.google.com", 80 )
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new( "/search?num=20&hl=en&noj=1&q=accept-encoding&btnG=Search", { "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip", "User-Agent" => "gzip" } )debug.call( "Performing HTTP GET request for (#{req.path})." )
res = http.request( req )      
debug.call( "Received HTTP Response Code (#{res.code})" )
case res
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    begin
      if res.header[ 'Content-Encoding' ].eql?( 'gzip' ) then
        debug.call( "Performing gzip decompression for response body." )
        #sio = StringIO.new( res.body )
        #gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new( sio )
        #page = gz.read() 
        page = res.body     
        debug.call( "Finished decompressing gzipped response body." )
      else  
        debug.call( "Page is not compressed. Using text response body. " )
        page = res.body 
      end   
    rescue Exception
      debug.call( "Error occurred (#{$!.message})" )
      # handle errors 
      raise $!.message
    end   
end

puts page
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, i'll give that a try.

Comment: Your Ruby is likely better than mine. You need to write the contents of `page` to a file and that's it you have not decompressed the response from the API.